# Sending large mail attachements over multiple mails

Tags: spring-boot, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am using Java Spring MimeMessageHelper to send mail (using SMTP). Mails can have multiple attachments(Size may exceed SMTP server's mail send limit) .

For eg. I can have 4-5 attachment in a mail and total size of them can exceed the limit. So I want to send 2 attachment over first mail and then other 3 attachments in next mail(According to their size).

Any pointers are appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to send more than your server will allow you to send?  If there were a way around the server limit, what would be the point of having a server limit?

Your best bet is to put the attachments on a web server somewhere and send a link to them instead of including them in the email.

If each attachment is small enough, you can also send multiple messages, each message with just enough attachments to avoid exceeding the size limit.

Comment: Thanks Bill , i think i was not much clear while putting the question. I can have 4-5 attachment in a mail and total size of them can exceed the limit. So I want to send 2 attachment over first mail and then other 3 attachments in next mail(According to their size).                                              Recipients want to take it in mail only. Is there anything i can do about it?

Comment: You can send two messages. What's the problem?

Comment: ok, I have not given a try yet .Using data handlers and iterating over attachements for their sizes? Thanks Bill

Comment: Yes, if you can't predict how big the attachments are, iterate over them until the message would be too big, then send it and start a new message.

Comment: I updated my answer.  You might want to update your question as well to make it clearer what you were asking.